# Power Bi - Relations and filtering

Tags: powerbi

i dont know how to search my topic well, so i post this question:

I have a 5 Tables

dimensions

- Customer -> Relation to Sales (No. and Customer No.)
- Item -> Relation to Sales (No. and Item No.)
- Item Category -> Relation to Item (!) (Field in Item)
  facts
- Sales Orders
- Credit Memos

Also i have some calculated values that uses values from Sales Orders and Credit Memos.

In my Report i have all 5 tables. So when i click on a Customer, the report shows only values related to this customer and filters all items which have values for him. When i click on Items, the report shows only values related to this Item. When i mark both, the report shows only values related to this customer and the marked item.
The not marked values in the dimensions are

But:
When i click Items, the reports does not filter the Item Category. When i click the Item Category, it DOES filter the Items.

Combinded filters on Customers on Item Category also do not work.

Note: i dont want to use the field filters. i want that the user can click in the lists/tables/dimensiosn.

Define relations from facts and dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters propagate along relationship paths from the 1-side to the many-side, and in reverse only if you configure the relationship for "[bidirectional cross-filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-bidirectional-filtering)".

> Read A model relationship propagates filters applied on the column of
> one model table to a different model table. Filters will propagate so
> long as there's a relationship path to follow, which can involve
> propagation to multiple tables.
>
> Relationship paths are deterministic, meaning that filters are always
> propagated in the same way and without random variation. Relationships
> can, however, be disabled, or have filter context modified by model
> calculations that use particular DAX functions. For more information,
> see the Relevant DAX functions topic later in this article.

[Model Relationships in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-relationships-understand)